# How can i resolve Invalid value set for options Signed-By regarding source error?

Tags: command-line, repository, gpu-driver

I'm new to Ubuntu, and i think i messed up my repo.
Now i see the error

```
E: Invalid value set for option Signed-By regarding source https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ubuntu/ jammy/production/2328 (not a fingerprint)
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel.gpu.jammy.list
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

and the main reason for all this is that i tried to fix the screen of my hp probook 650G2 from randomly going black and on again, due to some reasons i don't know.
I've tried opening and cleaning the inside, unplugged and plugged cables, changed my OS from Windows 10 pro to Ubuntu 22.04, and i tried installing new drivers, following the guide first from
https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/driver/installation.html#ubuntu-install-steps
and later from
https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/install-intel-graphic-drivers and now i ended up messing things

Comment: There is an error in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel.gpu.jammy.list` file. Note that I left out a `/` in the file path, because it shouldn't be there. Please edit your question and add the contents of that file (don't make it a comment). The word `sudo` should not be in any source list file.